# Do offscreen UIScrollView pages amount to a great pixel-burden?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode, ios, uikit

I have a paging-enabled UIScrollView filled with hundreds of UIViewControllers, each adding its UIView (a PDF page) to the UIScrollView. In terms of performance, with a large number of offscreen pages, is there more of a burden due to the large number of offscreen pixels needed to be drawn into the buffer for the Scroll view? I seek general answers relating to the method in which offscreen pixel drawing of UIScrollView occurs.

Comment: I am curious why each PDF page needs its own scrollview.

Comment: @sosborn each UIViewController has its own PDF page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes , you are actually bearing two costs here. One for the initialization/allocation of the thousand views and the other for rendering those when you add them to the scrollView. I would recommend creating a 'sliding window' of 5 pages and creating each page on the fly.